# Do WiFi networks see the MAC address the PC or the wireless card?

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm temporarily living in managed accommodation with no wired network so I purchased a WiFi card for my headless server. It authenticates devices by MAC address and I'm not sure which address to tell it to look for.

Comment: Please split unrelated questions into separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something authenticates devices by MAC address, then it's the MAC address of whatever you're using to connect to the network. If it's by WiFi, then it's the MAC address of the WiFi card/USB. If it's by ethernet, then it's the MAC address of the ethernet card.